# blank output of post contents

Tags: php, post, echo

i always get blank result when i echo post content or insert it into my database$
here is my code

**PHP**

```
<?php

$host = "mysql.1freehosting.com";
$user = "u249494946_user";
$pass = "aqwaqwaqw";
$db = "u249494946_first";

mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);
mysql_select_db($db);

/*if(isset($_post["ajout"])) {
echo("error submitting");
}
else {
*/
var_dump(isset($_post['submit']));
$nom = $_post["nom"];
$prenom = $_post["prenom"];
echo $_post[nom];
echo $nom;
$result1=mysql_query("INSERT INTO eleve (id,nom,prenom) VALUES (NULL,'$nom','$prenom')");var_dump($result1);
/*$result2=mysql_query("INSERT INTO eleve(id, nom, prenom) VALUES (null,'y','y')");
if(!$result1){
die('errreur result1 :' . mysql_error());
}
*/
var_dump($_POST);

?>
```

**HTML**

```
<html>
<head>

<title>disaster</title>
</head>
<body>
<div align="center">
<form  id="form" method="post" action="ajout.php">

nom : <input type="text" id="nom" />
prenom : <input type="text" id="prenom" />
<input type="submit" value="ajouter"  id="submit" />

</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

this is the result that i get

```
bool(false)
bool(true)
array(3) {
  ["nom"]=>
  string(7) "example"
  ["prenom"]=>
  string(7) "example"
  ["submit"]=>
  string(7) "ajouter"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$_POST` is a [`superglobal`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php) and MUST be in uppercase.

Change all your `$_post` to `$_POST`

Plus, as already stated by `Alon`, you need to name your input element:

```
<input type="text" id="nom" name="nom" />
```

credit goes to Alon for this.

I also recommend that you switch to [`mysqli_*`](http://php.net/mysqli) functions with [**prepared statements**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) or [**PDO**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) as [`mysql_*`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php) functions are deprecated and will be removed from future PHP releases.

---

### Edit

Some of your input elements are not named:

Change to:

```
nom : <input type="text" id="nom" name="name" />
prenom : <input type="text" id="prenom" name="prenom" />
<input type="submit" value="ajouter" name="submit" id="submit" />
```

Comment: it's actually `Alon` :)

Comment: bool(false)
bool(true)
array(0) {
}
now the array is always 0

Comment: Oh Lordy I sincerely apologize, I read too fast. I will remedy that right away. @Alon

Comment: Your `<input type="text" id="prenom" />` also did not have a name to it. See my edit, or change to `<input type="text" id="prenom" name="prenom" />` @MahmoudSenSei

Comment: Ah good, that's great news @MahmoudSenSei and you're welcome.

Answer (score 2):

It should be `echo $_POST["nom"];` instead of `echo $_post[nom];`

EDIT:
you need to add name attributes to the form inputs like `<input type="text" id="nom" name="nom" />`